# how to create a protobuf go plugin plugin

Tags: plugins, grpc, protoc

https://github.com/golang/protobuf

`protoc-gen-go` is a plugin in protoc which generates go bindings for the input proto definition.

`protoc-gen-go` also has a plugin framework for which `grpc` is a plugin plugin
https://github.com/golang/protobuf/tree/master/protoc-gen-go/grpc

`$ protoc ./helloworld.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:.`

is it possible that that i write my own plugin and invoke it along with grpc plugin?

`$ protoc ./helloworld.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc+myplugin:.`

do i need to mandatory build my plugin into protoc-gen-go ?
if no, then how will the protoc-gen-go find myplugin ?

Comment: Some starting point could be found with this issue: https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/147

Answer (score 7):

protoc-gen-go is a protoc plugin.  I have written an example of another protoc plugin below for custom work.  I've also used plugins which invoke other plugins.

https://github.com/drekle/protoc-gen-goexample

Protoc finds these plugins by name `protoc-gen-<PLUGIN_NAME>` which it expects to be a binary in your path and will interpret the args it is passed, for example `--<PLUGIN_NAME>_out` instead of `--go_out` for your plugin